# How to disable SQL Express Automatic updates

Tags: windows-10, sql-server-express

I have a deployment of MS SQL Express 2019 on a Windows 10 machine and I want to disable SQL Automatic updated (any update it may receive).
How to do it?

Thanks

Comment: More a question for [su] or [sf], but if you go into Windows Update settings, you need to unselect Receive updates for other Microsoft Products. Having said that, why don't you want it to update?

Comment: I don't want it to update because I'm hosting a database in it in production. So when it updates the database is down for few minutes and the application does not work then.

Comment: Well updates do need to be done, so you anyway need to schedule an update window. If you need 100% uptime then you should think about Availability Groups etc.